# in the installation of ambari in the confirm host step ,I encounter the following error .please give me some guidance

Tags: ambari

Running setup agent script:

> Command start time 2018-09-04 17:53:01
>   ftp://mirror.us.oneandone.net/linux/distributions/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
>   [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f1c0:5c0:2::1:0:
>   Network is unreachable" Trying other mirror.

Comment: Without knowing anything about Ambari I can see that the error messages indicates that there is a network connectivity problem the server with IPv6 address 2607:f1c0:5c0:2::1:0. The solution is probably to fix this connection problem. Sometimes IPv6 is not correctly configured across the entire system and switching to only using IPv4 will fix the problem.

Comment: what can i do slove this problem??

Comment: You most likely need to resolve the network connection problem. I'm afraid I cannot provide more help than this. You need to troubleshoot and solve the problem locally.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that your node hostnames resolve to IPv6 addresses,and IPv6 networking is not actually configured properly.You can try to disable IPv6 and switch to using IPv4 (if you are actually using IPv4 addresses at your network). Follow https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345415/how-to-switch-to-ipv6-on-linux to do that.